# Django query with relations

Tags: python, sql, django, orm

I have a messy and old query that I'm trying to convert from SQL to Django ORM and I can't seem to figure it out.
As the original query is not something that should be public, heres something similair to what I'm working with:

Table 1
id

Table 2
Id
username
active
birthday 
table_1_fk

Table 3
Id
amount
table_1_fk

I need to end up with a list of active users (username), sorted by date, displaying the amount. Table1 references within table 2 and 3 are not in order. The main issues I'm having are:

- How do I retrieve these with just ORM (no looping/executing, or hardly any if I must)
- If I can't use solely ORM and do decide to just loop over the parts I need to, how would I even create a single object to display in a table without looping over everything multiple times?

My tought processes:

> Table 2 is active -> get table 1 -> find table 1 pk in table 3 -> add table 3 info to table 1?
>
> Table 1 -> get table 2 Actives, Table1 -> get table 3 amounts -> loop to match according to table1_fks

Answer (score 0):

You can perform related references using the Table1. If your models looks something like this:

```
from django.db import models
from django.db.models import F

class Table1(models.Model):
    ...

class Table2(models.Model):
    username = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    active = models.BooleanField()
    birthday = models.DateField()  # Sorted by date
    table1 = models.ForeignKey(Table1, related_name="table2")

class Table3(models.Model):
    amount = models.IntegerField()
    table1 = models.ForeignKey(Table1, related_name="table3")
```

You can do later:

```
>>> users = (
    Table1.objects
        .filter(table2__active=True)
        .annotate(
            username=F("table2__username"), 
            amount=F("table3__amount"), 
            birthday=F("table2__birthday")
        )
        .order_by("-birthday")
        .values("username", "amount", "birthday")
)
>>> print(users)
[
  ["user1", 100.0, "2020-01-13"],
  ["user2", 890.0, "2020-01-10"],
  ["user3", None, "2020-01-01"],
]
```

It completely depends on how your models classes are implemented.